# Too many or Too few line

Tags: arrays, vb.net, csv

Below is a piece of code that re compiles an array into a csv like file.

```
Dim File As New System.IO.StreamWriter(varFileName)
    Dim NumberOfRows As Long = Array.GetUpperBound(0) ' Count number of rows.
    Dim NumberOfColumns As Long = Array.GetUpperBound(1) ' Count number of columns.

    Dim FileRows(NumberOfRows) As String
    File.Write("")
    'The idea here is to make up the row first by adding all of the columns together then write each row to the file.
    For i0 = 0 To NumberOfRows 'Loop through all of the Rows
        For i1 = 0 To NumberOfColumns 'Loop through all of the Columns
            If FileRows(i0) = "" Then 'Check if it is the first column then we dont need the ","
                FileRows(i0) = Array(i0, i1) 'If it is the first column we start the row with the first column
            Else
                FileRows(i0) = FileRows(i0) + ","c + Array(i0, i1) 'Now we take what we have so far and add "," and add the the next column
            End If
        Next ' We repeat this process untill of of the columns are written to a row.

        File.Write(FileRows(i0)) ' Now we write that row to the file.

    Next ' Move on to the next row.

    File.Close()
```

(please ignore my horrible coding practice)

However as shown above the file is saved with no new lines and is all mashed onto one line.

If i change the line `File.Write(FileRows(i0))` to `File.WriteLine(FileRows(i0))` line breaks are added that quickly increase the size of the file.

I'm guessing the first version of the code is more correct but I'm not sure how to fix the lack of line break. Any assistance would be much appreciated.
PS dumb it down a bit, I've been staring at this code for two days and my mind has melted a little.

Adding the csv to array code in case it's an issue with this instead.

```
 Dim FileData As New System.IO.StreamReader(varFileName)

    Dim FileRows() As String = FileData.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine) 'Read in each row.
    Dim NumberOfRows As Long = FileRows.GetUpperBound(0) ' Count number of rows.

    Dim FileColumns() As String = FileRows(0).Split(","c) 'Split row 1 data in to columns.
    Dim NumberOfColumns As Long = FileColumns.GetUpperBound(0) ' Count number of columns.

    ReDim dataArray(NumberOfRows, NumberOfColumns) 'Declare the array correctly with new data

    For x = 0 To NumberOfRows 'Cycle through all the rows
        FileColumns = FileRows(x).Split(","c) 'Split row into columns
        For y = 0 To NumberOfColumns 'Now cycle through all the columns on that row
            Try
                dataArray(x, y) = FileColumns(y) 'Set each piece of data into the array.
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        Next
    Next

    FileData.Close() 'This piece of code takes the csv file and turns it into an array. The data can now be called using Array(1,1) to get the first value
```

Comment: You are trying to add line breaks without increasing the size of the file? That's not possible. But it shouldn't really cause that much size increase.

Comment: Unfortunately when retrieving from the file that code can't handle extra line spacing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
File.Write(FileRows(i0)) ' Now we write that row to the file.
```

to

```
File.WriteLine(FileRows(i0)) ' Now we write that row to the file.
```

Try this specifically, get rid of you FileRows (you have no need to keep your lines right?)

```
For i0 = 0 To NumberOfRows 'Loop through all of the Rows
    Dim Line as string = nothing
    For i1 = 0 To NumberOfColumns 'Loop through all of the Columns
        If line is nothing Then 'Check if it is the first column then we dont need the ","
            line = Array(i0, i1) 'If it is the first column we start the row with the first column
        Else
            line &= ","c + Array(i0, i1) 'Now we take what we have so far and add "," and add the the next column
        End If
    Next ' We repeat this process until all of the columns are written to a row.

    File.WriteLine(line) ' Now we write that row to the file.

Next ' Move on to the next row.
```

based on the comments below, I'm fairly positive you have extra characters in your array causing the extra lines. To confirm this you can do a run by manually removing non standard characters with a REGEX like this (this is not functional code but a way to prove the extra characters are there)

```
Public nonAplaNum As New Regex("[^a-z_0-9]", RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)

' wrap each array assignment with this ...
line &= ","c + nonAlphaNum.replace(Array(i0, i1),"")
```

Comment: I saw your comment about already doing this, but you have no alternative if you need a line break.

Comment: The problem is when I do do this random line breaks appear all over my file.

Comment: I don't see anything that is actually wrong with your initial code except the missing "WriteLine". Are you sure your looking at the correct file output and not an old file output (or are appending to an old file output maybe)

Comment: The only other thing could be that you have somehow got linefeeds in your data (but you would see the breaks all over then too)

Comment: This nearly worked. Now I have a regular one extra line after each piece of data

Comment: ok, now it seems like you have a strangely defined "newline" character on your system. replace the `File.WriteLine(line)` with `File.Write(line & vblf)`  or possible just vbcr if vblf doesn't work.

Comment: If you r using a "split" command to get the lined data in the first place... if your data is CRLF delimited in the first place, and your only splitting by CR or LF then you would be leaving a rogue LF or a rogue CR on the end of each arrays row. that could be your root cause issue.

Comment: I see where you are coming from and what is happening makes a lot of sense. Unfortunately the solution doesn't work.

Comment: try changing `Dim FileRows() As String = FileData.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine)` to `Dim FileRows() As String = Split(FileData.ReadToEnd(),vbCrLf)`

Answer (score 0):

Just to speed up your code a little I would recommend a `StringBuilder` (though I know there are another 101 ways to skin the cat)...

```vb
Dim File As New System.IO.StreamWriter(varFileName)
Dim rows As Long = Array.GetUpperBound(0) ' Count number of rows.
Dim cols As Long = Array.GetUpperBound(1) ' Count number of columns.

For row As Integer = 0 To rows 'Loop through all of the Rows
    For col = 0 To cols 'Loop through all of the Columns
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        sb.Append(Array(col, row)
        If col < cols Then sb.Append(",")
    Next col ' We repeat this process untill of of the columns are written to a row.

    If sb.ToString().InexOf(vbCrLf) > 0 Then sb.Replace(vbCrLf, "")
    File.WriteLine(sb.ToString()) ' Now we write that row to the file.

Next row ' Move on to the next row.

File.Close()
```

I would recommend checking your array to see if there are any rogue CR/LFs or other breaking characters causing issues.

-- EDIT --

Added new section to check for and replace CrLf characters.

Comment: Any pointers on how to go about checking the array. Fairly new to VB and have never enjoyed multidimensional Arrays

Comment: @Calum: Apologies - Chrimbo & New Year etc.  I've updated the post with a check that will replace any `crlf`'s for you.